# Handling multiple resources requests in RESTful services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, restful-url, restful-architecture

I am confused on how to deal with requests that pass multiple resources.

I have the following hierarchy. Projects have deliverables and deliverables have documents. So Projects->Deliverables->Documents.

For custom actions specific to a document, let's say change_status, I have routes such as /projects/1/deliverables/1/documents/1/change_status. To this point all good.

But what would be the best practices when I want to change_status on several documents?
/projects/1/deliverables/1/documents/change_status (passing an array of documents ids) doesn't seem RESTFul as my understanding is that after "documents" and specific id should be present.

/projects/1/deliverables/1/change_status (passing an array of documents ids) doesn't convince me fot two reasons. First, my deliverables controller will be called (by convention in rails) and it also seems you are changing the status of a deliverable and not of documents. Given that status can be just changed in documents I think the resulting url is confusing, specially  if you could change status to deliverables too (how would you differentiate from changing status to deliverable or to documents, the url would be the same in this case).

SO basically I am confused on how to deal with request that handle several resources in RESTFul. ANy help/clarification would be very much appreciated! Thanks folks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic RESTful URL conventions are definitely not meant to be applied religiously in every case, you need to use your best judgement as to what makes sense when you get beyond the standard CRUD scenarios.

If you plan to always change the status of documents within a deliverable, then I'd go with (like you suggested): /projects/1/deliverables/1/documents/change_status

If you plan to change the status of documents across deliverables and projects, then I'd go with a separate route directly to documents, such as: /documents/change_status

Either way, you'll need to pass an array of document_id params.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should just call the status sub-resource "status" in the URL, not change_status.

```
PATCH /documents/status HTTP/1.1

approved=true&id=7&id=12
```

Comment: Well, it is change_)status because it is an action more than a resource. There is no such a thing a a Status in my app but you can change the status property of a document. I thought that, since it represents an action (this is an API that will use other clients) I add the verb to it. Am I wrong here?

Comment: Yes, I think you are wrong. A property of a resource *is* a resource, just a much smaller one. Is the "status" a thing (a noun)? Could you conceivable want to GET it (to find out what value it has)? For all usages of the word I can think of, I'd say yes. In a RESTful API, URIs only represent nouns, and HTTP methods represent the verbs. Use POST, PUT or PATCH to change the value of a status either by sending the request to /document/123 (status not exposed seperatly) or to /document/123/status (exposed seperatly). Either is good practice.